# About using quad in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I encounter a strange problem with `quad` function.
I was using `quad` to calculate simple integral, and it worked for 10 to 20 times, then Matlab issues the following error:

```
Error using quad (line 75)
The integrand function must return an output vector of the same length as the input vector. 
yteor(k) = quad(@(q)(exp(-(q).^2).*q.^2/(k.^2+1)), 0, 1);
```

Here q and k are scalars.
I can not get what is wrong and why it worked several hours ago.

**Edit**

Here is my code

```
for k=1:100,
    xteor(k)=step*k;
    yteor(k)=quad(@(q)(exp(-(q).^2).*q.^2/((step.*k+1).^2)),0,1);
end plot(xteor,yteor,'r');
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty self-explanative. Could you show your code? (ideally, working and not working one)

Comment: The whole code is too big so i will send the part which integrate and plot the graph:

Comment: for k=1:100
xteor(k)=step*k;
yteor(k)=quad(@(q)(exp(-(q).^2).*q.^2/((step.*k+1).^2)),0,1);
end
plot(xteor,yteor,'r');

Comment: Matlab thinks that i send him a vector but I send him a scalar.

Comment: You can edit your question (grey link under the post), and try to use Markdown formatting. Finally, it is often well seen to provide full working example (here, adding `step`, `xteor` and `yteor`initialisation.

Comment: the code works fine for me. I would suggest you modify step to another variable name, such as `stepInterval`, as step is also a function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet works for me on Octave (Matlab GNU clone)

```
step = 1;
xteor = zeros(100,1);
yteor = zeros(100,1);

for k=1:100,
  xteor(k)=step*k;
  yteor(k)=quad(@(q)(exp(-(q).^2).*q.^2/((step.*k+1).^2)),0,1);
end
plot(xteor,yteor,'r');
pause
```

My hypothesis is that your error is the consequence of something else happening earlier in your code (maybe related to `step` not being a scalar?). Instead of focusing on this line where the error arise. Try to search what you have changed just before the error appear.

Comment: Yep, thank you. I looked through the code and found that somewhere I occasinally put "."))) Anyway thanks a lot for help!!!